# How to implement two level isolation for pytest tests?

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, pytest

I have pytest tests isolated with scope function using this common method:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def db(schema, connection):
    trans = connection.begin()
    session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=connection))
    session.begin_nested()

    @event.listens_for(session, "after_transaction_end")
    def restart_savepoint(session, transaction):
        if transaction.nested and not transaction._parent.nested:
            session.expire_all()

            session.begin_nested()

    schema.session = session

    yield schema

    schema.session.close()
    trans.rollback()
```

I have fixtures that create test data. Then I test application with api calls that work with this test data. Let's say like this:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def foo(db):
    foo = Foo(
        bar="baz",
    )

    foo.save()
    return foo

def test_delete(self, client, foo):
    result = client.delete(f'{endpoint}/{foo.id}')
    ...
```

At this point everything works great. But I want to speed up tests. And the way I see is to create test data with the scope of class or more and rollback changes made in every test (to keep test data unchanged for every test).
I tried this:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='class')
def db(schema, connection):
    yield schema


@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def db_function_scope(schema, connection):
    trans = connection.begin()
    session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=connection))
    session.begin_nested()

    @event.listens_for(session, "after_transaction_end")
    def restart_savepoint(session, transaction):
        if transaction.nested and not transaction._parent.nested:
            session.expire_all()

            session.begin_nested()

    schema.session = session

    yield schema

    schema.session.close()
    trans.rollback()

@pytest.fixture(scope='class')
def foo(db):
    foo = Foo(
        bar="baz",
    )

    foo.save()
    return foo

def test_delete(self, db_function_scope, client, foo):
    result = client.delete(f'{endpoint}/{foo.id}')
    ...
```

Which resulted in 2 problems:

1. foo object is detached from the session
2. some tests after execution and won't proceed to the next test

This part is solved by expire_on_commit=False

Now I have another problem: Some tests in random order fail with error "a transaction is already begun for this connection"

Ideally, I also want to delete test data according to "db" fixture scope
At this point I'm out of ideas.

Thank you in advance for help